# Forward all traffic from ethernet via SSH tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, 15.04, proxy

I have an Ubuntu laptop that has access to the Internet over Wifi (Machine A). I have another Ubuntu machine that doesn't have a Wifi card (Machine B).

I connect machine A to machine B with an ethernet cable. I can access the Internet. But what I want to do is have machine B access the Internet via an SSH tunnel on machine A.

Is it possible to forward any connection via ethernet on machine A through an SSH tunnel?

```
B -> A -> Internet -> SSH Tunnel (Server)
```

Comment: when you want a tunnel, you need two points to connect. `A -> Internet` does not look like two points. Where the tunnel should lead?

Comment: @Jakuje Oops well spotted. I was meant to put Internet before SSH Tunnel.

Comment: One possibility is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN the other would be to set up A as a proxy jump and run SOCKS proxy to the server, but still too long to explain here.

Comment: But would this allow me to only send ethernet traffic through the tunnel? I currently do this `ssh -D5235 user@server` but I want my ethernet traffic to go through a different tunnel/proxy.